# Vector data written to binary file isn't the same when read back into another vector, why?

Tags: c++, file, binary

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "ReadText.h"
using namespace std;

const string FILE_NAME = "TopicIinBasic.txt";

template<typename T>
char * as_bytes( T &inType );


int main()
{
    vector<int> vec(2, 2);

    vector<int> receive(2);

    fstream write( "myFile.dat", ios::out | ios::binary );

    write.write( as_bytes(vec[0]), sizeof(vec[0] * 2) );

    write.close();

    fstream read( "myFile.dat", ios::in | ios::binary );

    read.read( as_bytes(receive[0]), sizeof(vec[0] * 2) );

    cout << receive[0] << ' ' << receive[1] << endl;    

    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
char * as_bytes( T &inType )
{
    void* addr = &inType;

    return static_cast<char*>(addr);
}
```

I first write the contents of `vec` to the binary file. Then close the file. Then open it again in read mode. Then I try to put the contents of the binary file into `receive`. But when I display `receive`'s contents, the output is `2 0`, not `2 2`. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the actual file contents (if you open it in a hex editor)?

Comment: also, what's `const string FILE_NAME` there for?  And `#include "ReadText.h"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the size of the expression `vec[0] * 2`, which is the same size as `vec[0]`. As a result, you're only writing one element!

Moving the `* 2` outside the parentheses will fix it. (I've also moved it up front for clarity.)

```
write.write( as_bytes(vec[0]), 2 * sizeof(vec[0]) );
```

Comment: Note that the same issue exists in the call to read, as well.

Comment: Right -- same code there, same problem. Fix them both, obviously!

Comment: Just wanted to point it out, since fixing write would still show an issue if the OP didn't notice ;)